# Zeroth homology of the complement of a closed set

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, real-analysis, gn.general-topology

Suppose $F$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n>1$.
Are there some known conditions that must be imposed on $F$ so that its complement in $\mathbb{R}^n$  has a finite number of components? Equivalently, that the zeroth homology group $H_0(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F)$ is isomorphic to $\oplus_{k=1}^m\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: There's a problem with your last formula.

Comment: Certainly relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality